# How to view pictures as gallery in windows 11 without installing additional apps or software?

Tags: windows-11

I have Windows 11. I have a folder with images in it. When I open an image by double-clicking the file, I see a preview but I cannot cycle through the images using my arrow keys. How can I do that?

This is what I see in the ribbon:

[image]

Under the View I see:

- Extra Large Icons
- Large Icons
- Medium Icons
- Small Icons
- Details
- Content
- List

I tried searching for solution online but could not find it.

Comment: You should see in Explorer under *View > Show* the option to enable "Preview pane". Clicking on it will enable showing the preview of the current image.

Comment: The preview pane opens a pane to the right side but does not allow me to cycle through the images using arrow keys once I double-click an image. i.e., it does something completely different from what I want to achieve.

Comment: You move through the images on the left. The Preview pane will always show the *current image*. It is not interactive and does not react to key-presses.

Answer (score 0):

You should see in Explorer, under the menu *View > Show*,
an option to enable the "Preview pane".
Clicking on it will enable showing the preview of the current image.

You move through the images on the left. The Preview pane will always
show the *current image*.